# Differentiable linear mappings

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations

I'm reading *Advanced calculus of several variable*, by Edwards C.H. On page 60 is written the following theorem : **Theorem 1.2.** "The mapping $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R^m}$ is differentiable at $a\in \Bbb{R^m}$ if and only if  there exists a linear mapping $L:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R^m}$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)}{h}=\bar{0}\space\space\space\space\space(6)$$

in which case $L$ is defined by $L(h)=d_{fa}(h)=hf'(a)."$

It would seem like $(6)$ is trying to convey the idea, that $f'(a)$ maybe approximated by some linear mapping $L(h)$, provided of course that $h$ is small. In the proof of the "$\leftarrow$" direction is written : **"Suppose there exists a linear mapping satisfying $(6)$. Then there exists $\bar{b} \in \Bbb{R^m}$ such that $L(h)=h\bar{b}"$**

There is no reference to any theorem, but it seems like the existence of such a $\bar{b}$ draws from the fact that $L(h)=hf'(a)$ and some connection between $f'(a)$ and $\bar{b}$. How can we conclude the existence of this $\bar{b}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not $f'(a)$ but $f(a+h)-f(a)$ may be approximated by a linear application. The writing $h\bar b$ is strange. But, if $L:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ is linear, there is a matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ s.t. $L(h)=Ah$. So, in your case, $A\in \mathbb R^{m\times 1}$, and $Ah=h A$, so $\bar b$ is just the matrix of $L$.